# Titanium: AlarmMananger Module and Cancelling Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am currently using version 0.11 of the [AlarmManager](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager) module for my Titanium app (currently built with version 3.2.2 of the SDK).  I am noticing some odd behavior when cancelling alarms, specifically when cancelling a notification after resuming the app.  Here is the case:

In some cases, when the app is put into the background, a reminder notification may be set for a configurable amount of time in the future.  If the user resumes the app before this notification fires, the app should cancel the pending notification, as the user doesn't need it.  However, the notification is not being cancelled.  Now, I see in the log that the module is attempting to cancel the notification (using the correct request code for the notification), and no error is thrown by either my app or the module, but, again, the notification is not cancelled.

In testing, if I create a notification via the module in the app, and cancel that notification without pausing the app, that notification is cancelled correctly.

I suspect this has something to do with a context switch when the app resumes (since the module relies on the app's current context when spinning up the notification service), but I'm not sure why this occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually had to do with the type of the request code being sent to the alarm module's cancel function.  If the type of the request code variable is not a number (as in java.lang.Number), the module uses a default request code, which would not match the code of the previously scheduled alarm.